# I'm still getting error of recursion in python: memory error stack overflow

Tags: python, recursion

Me And My friends Are working on a project in python.We coding some that every emails sent on an inbox he search on a list and if he find on the list,script execute some action on a web site.
The Problem is that when we run the script after some time we get recursion error of stack!
we modified the code for increasing in this way adding `sys.setrecursionlimit(sys.getrecursionlimit() + 100)` but after many hours script gives: **Memory error!Stack Overflow**!

This is the entire script code:

````
import zmail
import time
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

server = zmail.server('EMAIL', 'PASSWORD')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)


sheet = client.open("SHEET LIST").sheet1
#sheet.update_cell(1, 6, "Error!")


def check():
   sair = False
   mailbox_info = server.stat()
   sys.setrecursionlimit(sys.getrecursionlimit() + 100)
   if mailbox_info[0] > 0:
       total = mailbox_info[0]
       for x in range(0, total):
           #print(x)
           body = server.get_mail(total - x)
           body = body['content_text']
           body = str(body)
           print(body)
           row = len(sheet.col_values(1))
           emails = sheet.col_values(1)
           passwords = sheet.col_values(2)
           keys = sheet.col_values(4)
           contador = 0
           while sair == False:
               #print(row)
               #print(contador)
               if body.find(str(emails[contador])) != -1:
                   #print("if")
                   f = open("log.txt", "a")
                   email = str(emails[contador])
                   passw = str(passwords[contador])
                   key = str(keys[contador])
                   print("Found this email " + email)
                   f.write("Found this email " + email + "\n")
                   driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
                   try:
                       driver.get("WEBSITE FOR DOING ACTION")
                   except:
                       sheet.update_cell(contador + 1, 6, "Error!")
                       sair = True
                   email_in = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/input")
                   email_in.send_keys(email)
                   print("Writing email...")
                   f.write("Writing email... \n")
                   password_in = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/input")
                   password_in.send_keys(passw)
                   print("Writing password...")
                   f.write("Writing password... \n")
                   key_in = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[6]/input")
                   key_in.send_keys(key)
                   print("Writing key...")
                   f.write("Writing key... \n")
                   checkbox_in = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/label[2]/input")
                   driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", checkbox_in)
                   print("Selecting checkbox...")
                   f.write("Selecting checkbox... \n")
                   button_in = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[8]")
                   print("Clicking button...")
                   f.write("Clicking button... \n")
                   driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button_in)
                   time.sleep(120)
                   if driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/p[2]").is_displayed():
                       sheet.update_cell(contador + 1, 6, "Success!")
                   else:
                       sheet.update_cell(contador + 1, 6, "Error!")
                   driver.close()
                   contador += 1
                   if contador >= row:
                       sair = True
                   #sair = True
               else:
                   #print("else")
                   contador += 1
                   if contador >= row:
                       sair = True
           contador = 0
           timeC()

   else:
       timeC()


def timeC():
   time.sleep(10) ```
````

But i know the error is in this part of code

```
 timeC()

    else:
        timeC()

def timeC():
    time.sleep(10) 
check()


timeC()
```

**How We Can Resolve Guys?**

This is traceback with recursion limit outside of the check:

```
File "main.py", line 100, in timeC
    check()
  File "main.py", line 95, in check
    timeC()
  File "main.py", line 100, in timeC
    check()
  File "main.py", line 95, in check
    timeC()
  File "main.py", line 100, in timeC
    check()
  File "main.py", line 95, in check
    timeC()
  File "main.py", line 100, in timeC
    check()
  File "main.py", line 95, in check
    timeC()
  File "main.py", line 100, in timeC
    check()
  File "main.py", line 95, in check
    timeC()
  File "main.py", line 100, in timeC
    check()
  File "main.py", line 95, in check
    timeC()
  File "main.py", line 100, in timeC
    check()
  File "main.py", line 25, in check
    mailbox_info = server.stat()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\zmail\server.py", line 129, in stat
    with self.pop_server as server:
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\zmail\abc.py", line 78, in __enter__
    self.login()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\zmail\server.py", line 306, in login
    self._make_server()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\zmail\server.py", line 290, in _make_server
    self.server = poplib.POP3_SSL(self.host, self.port, timeout=self.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\poplib.py", line 447, in __init__
    POP3.__init__(self, host, port, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\poplib.py", line 102, in __init__
    self.sock = self._create_socket(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\poplib.py", line 450, in _create_socket
    sock = POP3._create_socket(self, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\poplib.py", line 108, in _create_socket
    return socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 707, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
RecursionError: encoding with 'idna' codec failed (RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison)
```

Comment: How is `check()` ever called?

Comment: Could you include the stack trace you get when the overflow error is raised?

Comment: I don't see check() being called, but does it call itself in driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", checkbox_in) ?

Comment: Sorry check is called,but i didn't copied all code,now i edited the code and you can see

Comment: Indentation errors, so impossible to tell, but take out everything from check except timeC. call check(). It should reproduce, if my guess is correct, but hard to tell without a [mcve] and correct indentation in the stackoverflow question.

Comment: The only possible way that recursion can happen, based on the code you've provided, is if `check()` does something that results in `check()` getting called. IDK that much about the webdriver stuff, Do you expect it to call `check()` somehow?

Comment: A crazier idea is that your indentation is all wrong and `timeC()` is actually calling `check()`.

Comment: @mojo what is the correct code for you?

Comment: @JhonHelmut A stack trace will tell us a lot more than analysis of your pasted code. It'll tell us which function is being recursively called and from where. Since there's no explicit recursion in the code you've posted, I can't think of a good reason why you'd want recursion. Set the recursion depth to something really small and get a stack trace.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 105, in <module>
    timeC()
  File "main.py", line 101, in timeC
    check()
  File "main.py", line 26, in check
    sys.setrecursionlimit(1)
RecursionError: cannot set the recursion limit to 1 at the recursion depth 4: the limit is too low @mojo

Comment: Set the recursion limit outside `check()`; Put the stacktrace in your post (easier to read).

Comment: i edit post with traceback can you check? @mojo

Comment: Included @samwise

Comment: The stack trace shows that `timeC` calls `check`, but this is not what the code you pasted shows.  If `timeC` calls `check` that's obviously why you'd hit a recursion limit.  There's no reason to have these functions call each other recursively; just use a normal loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You did not correctly paste your code into your question.  The stack trace shows that your `timeC` function is the culprit, because it recursively calls `check`, presumably something like:

```
def timeC():
   time.sleep(10)
   check()
```

2. You're trying to do an infinite loop via recursion, which is a bad decision in Python since tail calls don't pop the stack; infinite recursion will use infinite stack memory.  Instead you should just do a simple loop outside of `check`.  Get rid of `timeC` and your calls to it, and do something like this:

```
while True:
    check()
    sleep(10)
```

Inside `check`, when the check is done, `return` instead of making a recursive call.  Let the outer loop take care of scheduling the next check.

Comment: GOD BLESS YOU. seems that i've resolved with this. only need to change `sleep` with `time.sleep`. thank you for your help. i will let you know if some other error happens.